# Reg Exp which should not allow three or more consecutive digits in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I wanted to write a validation to a name field which should not accept three consecutive digits in the field.
For example:

- a&c12s - success
- 12b_1 - success
- ab12@c23d - success
- a*c12 - success
- abc123G - failure
- abc123456K - failure
- 1234Ks - failure
- ab12sp1234k - failure

here is the code i already have:

```
&lt;xf:constraint id="name-constraint" value="string(.)=&quot;&quot; or matches(.,&quot;^[-a-zA-Z0-9/.,()*+_&amp;'@#% ]*$&quot;)"/&gt;
```

please suggest modifications in this.

Comment: Previously it was like ^[-a-zA-Z0-9/.,()*+_&amp;'@#% ]*$
but now  i want to modify it to allow only upto 2 consecutive digits

Answer (score 2):

`^(?!.*\d{3})` should work. It will fail to match if the string contains 3 or more consecutive digits.

[demo here](https://regex101.com/r/6Ab0nP/1)

Answer (score 1):

### Matching invalid inputs

Instead of trying to find a regexp which **fails** if there are three or more digits, you could reverse the problem and find a regexp which **matches** if there are three or more digits, as other answers have suggested. Then, if it matches, the input is invalid; if it does not, it is valid. That regexp of course is just

```
/\d{3}/
```

### Matching valid inputs

If you really want a regexp which matches only valid strings, then you need:

```
/^(\D|\d(\D|$)|\d\d(\D|$))*$/
```

This says:

> The entire string from beginning (`^`) to end (`$`) is a sequence (`*`) of segments, each of which is either (`|`) not a digit (`\D`), or a digit (`\d`) followed by not-a-digit (or end of string), or two digits followed by not-a-digit (or end of string).

This solution has the weakness that it is not very scalable--in other words, it would be very messy to change it to find sequences of 10 or more digits.

### Negative look-aheads

@TheLostMind's answer gives what is probably the best solution, if you are willing to learn negative-lookaheads:

```
/^(?!.*\d{3})/
  ^^^ NEGATIVE LOOKAHEAD
```

This says:

> Match at the beginning of the string (`^`) **if**, looking ahead one does **not** see (`(?!`) some arbitrary characters followed by three digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can test for :

```
new RegExp("[0-9]{3,}")
```

or : 
`/[0-9]{3,}/`

and if you want a shortcut : 
`/\d{3,}/`  where \d represents digits from 0-9
If your string matches, it contains 3 or more digits in a row.